# JButton and ActionListener Issue

Tags: java, swing

Hey guys I really appreciate any help but I was recently coding this easy software and ran into a weird issue. I was trying to use an ActionListener but I some how messed up. Its been awhile since I have done this. Sorry if this is just a careless mistake.

Code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class startScreen implements ActionListener {
    JFrame mainFrame;
    JPanel mainPanel;
    JButton gotIt;

    private final String gotItText = "Got It!";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        startScreen a = new startScreen();

        a.screenSetup();
    }

    private void screenSetup() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        gotIt = new JButton();

        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.add(gotIt);

        gotIt.setText(gotItText);

        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        JButton buttonPressed = (JButton) arg0.getSource();
        if (buttonPressed==gotIt) {
            System.out.println("gotIt has been pressed!");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What's the issue exactly? You may have just forgotten to add the ActionListener to the JButton...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add your actionListener to the component that you want. Here the problem is you defined a function but you did not add it to your button.
I think this link gives you a very good understanding about how it works.

http://alvinalexander.com/java/jbutton-listener-pressed-actionlistener

Comment: Haha thats what I forgot!